# download images using URL and then show them using custom PagerAdapter

Tags: android

I'd like to download a bunch of images from web and then show them using my custom `PagerAdapter`. So I can slide to browse all of these images. Please see the following figure:

`HttpURLConnection` is used to download the image in background and `BitmapFactory` is used to produce the bitmap.

There is one problem for this app. It's not fluid when sliding to the next image. There is an obvious pause when showing the next image. How to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: There is a concept called LazyLoading.... Check it. It may help you

Comment: check this out it may help you : http://blog.jamesbaca.net/?p=67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont load the image in the background, it will block the Main thread, so your app is not so fluid.

you can try the following open source project:

1. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
2. https://github.com/lianghanzhen/ImageCacheAndLoader